# Is it possible to specify Active Directory username and password in connection string?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, authentication, authorization

My organization uses Active Directory to control access to our databases. Building web applications and as part of our CI process I would like to specify the credentials in the connection string.

Is it possible to pass AD credentials in a connection string or do I need a standard SQL account for these items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have your app impersonate a windows user and do the connection that way. [Example for ASP.net app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).